# Display time without quotes

Tags: php, arrays

I got below code;

```
$dy = $s[$i]['time'];
$date = date("Y/m/d", $dy);

$price = $s[$i]['price'];
```

which displays $date as 2018-05-03 and $price as 900. However if I use;

```
$array[] = array($date,$price);

echo json_encode($array);
```

the result is displayed as [["2018/05/03",900]]

How do I remove "" from the date so that it gets [[2018/05/03,900]]  displayed instead?

Comment: the json_encoded string is not meant to be displayed directly, but to only keep/send the data.

Comment: What is the purpose of echoing the json?

Comment: @Jeff I got it after reading further about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically speaking, you can't. You're encoding two strings into a JSON string and by design it's encapsulating that in quotes to denote it is in fact a string. This is handy because if you were to use `json_decode` and turn it back into an array, you'll then have the string again as it was before encoding.

`[[2018/05/03,900]]` is also not valid JSON anyway as it'll treat `2018/05/03` without quotes as an invalid integer. So you have to have the quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. You are right. I was trying to make a graph which was not showing date due to quotes. Anyway I solved it by deserializing the quotes in JS.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know the purpose why you need this but you can do one thing

Step 1.`$date = strtotime(date("Y/m/d", $dy));` convert date to `int` using strtotime

Step 2. `$array[] = array($date,$price); echo json_encode($array);`  now date will be considered as `int`

Step 3. when you want to use it simply convert the `int` generated by `strtotime` to date

`echo date("Y/m/d",$array[0][0]);`

Comment: Thanks for the answering. Though it did not solved my problem, it's a good way to look at it.